# How to display the correct sum() value based on the type

Tags: sql-server

```
TABLE 1         
STAFF_NO   TYPE      AMOUNT 
 A1         O         300   
 B3         A          10   
 A1         A          45   
 C3         O          70   
 C4         A         300   
 D4         O         100   

TABLE2  
STAFF_NO    CODE
 A1          SS1
 B3          SS1
 C3          SS2
 C4          SS2
 D4          SS2
```

I inner join 2 tables and select code, headcount and sum at up for both type for 'O' and 'A'based on code.
Here are my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.CODE, 
COUNT(DISTINCT B.CODE) AS HEADCOUNT, 
O=(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)  FROM TABLE1 WHERE TYPE ='O'),   
A=(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)  FROM TABLE1 WHERE TYPE ='A')
FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.STAFF_NO=B.STAFF_NO group by B.code
```

My Error: SS1 and SS2 on 'O' and 'A' have the same value.

```
CODE    HEADCOUNT   O   A
SS1         2     300   55
SS2         3     300   55
```

The result i should get:

```
CODE    HEADCOUNT   O   A
SS1        2      300   55
SS2        3      170   300
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is your friend.

```
SELECT
  B.CODE,
  COUNT(A.STAFF_NO) HEADCOUNT,
  SUM(CASE A.TYPE WHEN 'O' THEN A.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) O,
  SUM(CASE A.TYPE WHEN 'A' THEN A.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) A
FROM
  TABLE1 A 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.STAFF_NO = A.STAFF_NO
GROUP BY
  B.CODE
```

If `A.AMOUNT` can contain NULL, use `ISNULL`:

```
SUM(CASE A.TYPE WHEN 'O' THEN ISNULL(A.AMOUNT, 0) ELSE 0 END) O
```